# Google Analytics API authorization for CMS (Single authorization)

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a 'CMS' for use in clients websites and I would like to include a few analytics views. I have searched and I found some things like this one in google analytics demos and tools (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/), but it needs you to be logged with the analytics google account to show them.

I have seen Worpdress plugins that shows analytics in the dashboard and you only have to authorize them once and not to be logged in google. ¿How is this done?

I need to show client analytics in the dashboard of the CMS, but I don't want to ask for login everytime or request to be logged in their google accounts.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Try this answer I wrote a few days ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900120/5159168

Comment: @Andreas I would rather use some solution related with the API, so I can customize the charts with any library, but thanks!

Comment: Try it! It is API driven and you can customize the charts.

Comment: @Andreas Will give a try later, and post thoughts, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Analytics embedded API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) is built using JavaScript.  JavaScript is client sided and there for an implicit login.   Implicit logins do not contain a refresh token so when ever the access token expires normally after an hour you will need to login again.

Your Word press plugin assuming its the one i think it is.  Uses php and is there for server sided and uses a hybrid login which probably requested offline access from you when you authenticated it first time.   Offline access gives you a refresh token which can then be used to request a new access token when ever the plugin needs to access Google Analytics.

Assuming that your client only wants to see their own data they should be using a service account.  Service accounts are preauthorized and will there for not require that you authenticate them again.  Service accounts only work with server sided languages like php you can not use service account authentication with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I use PHP on the sever for the CMS, so I will try services accounts.

Comment: I tried your solution and decided to use service accounts. Thanks again!